# Entire file is in boldface for no apparent reason

Tags: overleaf, bold

I made my CV in Overleaf a while ago using a default CV template and it worked fine, but recently I wanted to translate it to English so I used the "copy" feature. When I open the copy project, the whole text is in bold and not just in the preview, but in the file itself.

I've tried to manually make a copy of the source files (ctrl + c and ctrl + v), both the .tex and .cls template but the problem still persists. The original file is still fine but any attempt at a copy is completely in bold, no matter how many times I recompile them.

Here is the template I used:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Medium Length Professional CV - RESUME CLASS FILE
%
% This template has been downloaded from:
% http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com
%
% This class file defines the structure and design of the template. 
%
% Original header:
% Copyright (C) 2010 by Trey Hunner
%
% Copying and distribution of this file, with or without modification,
% are permitted in any medium without royalty provided the copyright
% notice and this notice are preserved. This file is offered as-is,
% without any warranty.
%
% Created by Trey Hunner and modified by www.LaTeXTemplates.com
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\ProvidesClass{resume}[2010/07/10 v0.9 Resume class]

\LoadClass[11pt,letterpaper]{article} % Font size and paper type

\usepackage[parfill]{parskip} % Remove paragraph indentation
\usepackage{array} % Required for boldface (\bf and \bfseries) tabular columns
\usepackage{ifthen} % Required for ifthenelse statements

\pagestyle{empty} % Suppress page numbers

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   HEADINGS COMMANDS: Commands for printing name and address
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\def \name#1{\def\@name{#1}} % Defines the \name command to set name
\def \@name {} % Sets \@name to empty by default

\def \addressSep {$\diamond$} % Set default address separator to a diamond

% One, two or three address lines can be specified 
\let \@addressone \relax
\let \@addresstwo \relax
\let \@addressthree \relax

% \address command can be used to set the first, second, and third address (last 2 optional)
\def \address #1{
  \@ifundefined{@addresstwo}{
    \def \@addresstwo {#1}
  }{
  \@ifundefined{@addressthree}{
  \def \@addressthree {#1}
  }{
     \def \@addressone {#1}
  }}
}

% \printaddress is used to style an address line (given as input)
\def \printaddress #1{
  \begingroup
    \def \\ {\addressSep\ }
    \centerline{#1}
  \endgroup
  \par
  \addressskip
}

% \printname is used to print the name as a page header
\def \printname {
  \begingroup
    \hfil{\MakeUppercase{\namesize\bf \@name}}\hfil
    \nameskip\break
  \endgroup
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PRINT THE HEADING LINES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\let\ori@document=\document
\renewcommand{\document}{
  \ori@document  % Begin document
  \printname % Print the name specified with \name
  \@ifundefined{@addressone}{}{ % Print the first address if specified
    \printaddress{\@addressone}}
  \@ifundefined{@addresstwo}{}{ % Print the second address if specified
    \printaddress{\@addresstwo}}
     \@ifundefined{@addressthree}{}{ % Print the third address if specified
    \printaddress{\@addressthree}}
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   SECTION FORMATTING
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% Defines the rSection environment for the large sections within the CV
\newenvironment{rSection}[1]{ % 1 input argument - section name
  \sectionskip
  \MakeUppercase{\bf #1} % Section title
  \sectionlineskip
  \hrule % Horizontal line
  \begin{list}{}{ % List for each individual item in the section
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{1.5em} % Margin within the section
  }
  \item[]
}{
  \end{list}
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   WORK EXPERIENCE FORMATTING
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\newenvironment{rSubsection}[4]{ % 4 input arguments - company name, year(s) employed, job title and location
 {\bf #1} \hfill {#2} % Bold company name and date on the right
 \ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{}}{}{ % If the third argument is not specified, don't print the job title and location line
  \\
  {\em #3} \hfill {\em #4} % Italic job title and location
  }\smallskip
  \begin{list}{$\cdot$}{\leftmargin=0em} % \cdot used for bullets, no indentation
   \itemsep -0.5em \vspace{-0.5em} % Compress items in list together for aesthetics
  }{
  \end{list}
  \vspace{0.5em} % Some space after the list of bullet points
}

% The below commands define the whitespace after certain things in the document - they can be \smallskip, \medskip or \bigskip
\def\namesize{\huge} % Size of the name at the top of the document
\def\addressskip{\smallskip} % The space between the two address (or phone/email) lines
\def\sectionlineskip{\medskip} % The space above the horizontal line for each section 
\def\nameskip{\bigskip} % The space after your name at the top
\def\sectionskip{\medskip} % The space after the heading section
```

Edit: Writing from scratch an excerpt from my original file but using the same class -

```
\documentclass{resume}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[left=0.75in,top=0.6in,right=0.75in,bottom=0.6in]{geometry} % Document margins
\usepackage{siunitx}

\name{My Name}
\address{Class \\ Uni} 

\begin{document}

\begin{rSection}{Contact info}

\begin{tabular}{>{}l @{\hspace{6ex}} l }
Phone num. & 12345-6789 \\ \\
E-mail & email@example.com
% everything here is still bold
\end{tabular}

\end{rSection}


\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't get bold when I typeset a minimal document with that document class. Do you get it with *every* document with that class? If not, post a sample document that does. Someone else [recently had a very similar problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/655756/making-copy-of-document-makes-everything-bold#comment1634110_655756); there's no solution there but some suggestions you can check out. It might be something you need to ask Overleaf about.

Comment: @frabjous Updated the post with a minimal document that's very close to what I wrote in my original file. It's bold for me

Comment: I don't get all bold with that document with a local TeXlive 2022. You can try [clearing the cache and compiling from scratch](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Clearing_the_cache) but if the problem persists, you probably need to contact [Overleaf support](https://www.overleaf.com/contact), since the problem would appear to be on their end.

Answer (score 4):

After contacting Overleaf support, Paul sent me a very helpful response:
"When you copy a project in Overleaf, the new copy gets the most recent version of TeX Live, which is the LaTeX distribution that is used to compile your projects.

Sometimes, differences between the version of TeX Live used on your original project and the latest version can lead to differences in the appearance between the original project and the copy, or can even lead to compilation errors on the new copy of the project.
[...]
One way to solve the problems you are having is to change the copy to use the same version of TeX Live as your original."

Changing the TeX version to the same one as the original project (2019 TeX Live in my case) fixed the issue.

Comment: How exactly do you change the TeX Version? I am editing my CV in the Overleaf online editor by the way.